# Custom wifi interface is not been added to remembered network in API 27 device, but it does in API 25 device

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

I'm developing an app which main purpose is create a wifi interface, and try the device connect to it.

To implement this I use an MVVM patter, doing something like this:

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setUI()
        processWifiConfiguration(applicationContext)
    }

    private fun processWifiConfiguration(context: Context) {
       try {
           viewModel.launchWifiConfiguration(context = context)
       }catch (e:NullPointerException){
           Log.d("es.paytef", "configuredNetworks esta a null")
           e.printStackTrace()
       }

    }

    private fun setUI() {
        setContent {
            val viewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val isLoading by viewModel.isLoading.collectAsState()
            val context = LocalContext.current
            WifiCepsaManagerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    if(isLoading){
                        CenterLoadingText(applicationContext.getString(R.string.wait))
                    }else{
                        //Finnish activity
                        context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
                        this.finish()
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CenterLoadingText(name: String) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
        Text(
            text = name,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

And regarding the logic to up the interface is in my viewmodel:

SharedViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context) : ViewModel() {

    private val wifiManager: WifiManager =
        context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

    private val _isLoading: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isLoading: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    fun launchWifiConfiguration(context: Context) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _isLoading.emit(true)
            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled) {
                wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return@launch
            }
            val wifiConfiguration = createWifiConfiguration()
            try {
                connectWifi(
                    context = context,
                    wifiConfiguration = wifiConfiguration
                ).also {
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _isLoading.emit(false)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createWifiConfiguration(): WifiConfiguration {
        /**
         * Set the following wifi params:
         * Seguridad: 802.1x EAP
         * Método EAP: EAP PEAP
         * Autenticación fase 2: MSCHAPv2
         * Certificado CA: Sin certificado
         * Identidad: ***********
         * Identidad anónima: Nada
         * Contraseña: ******
         *
         */
        val wifiEnterpriseConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
        val wifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
        wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.phase2Method = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.caCertificate = null
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = null
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.identity = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_USER +"\""
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.password = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS +"\""
        wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig = wifiEnterpriseConfig
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_SSID +"\""
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey ="\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS+"\""

        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP)

        return wifiConfiguration
    }

    private fun connectWifi(
        context: Context,
        wifiConfiguration: WifiConfiguration,
    ) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return
        }
        //add the network
        val ssid = wifiManager.addNetwork(
            wifiConfiguration
        )
        //Enable all the interface
        wifiManager.configuredNetworks.map {
            it.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
        }
        wifiManager.disconnect()
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(ssid, true) // this initiates the connection
        wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
        wifiManager.reconnect()
       
    }

    fun getNetworkId(context: Context, ssid: String): Int {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return -1
        }
        val configurations = wifiManager.configuredNetworks
        for (config in configurations) {
            if (config.SSID != null && config.SSID.equals(ssid, true)) {
                return config.networkId
            }
        }
        return -1
    }
}
```

The present workflow is when I launch the app, in a A920 Pro device (API 25) the custom network is added to remembered networks, but if I launch the app in a IM30 device (API 27), the network is not been added.

I know that the WifiConfiguration class is deprecated, but the other approach, which is use WifiSuggestion, is not available under 29 level API device, so it's not an option.

Do you have some similar incident like this? And if like that, what am I missing?

after log an A920 divice, which have the same API than IM30 device, I've seen that addNetwork() method is returning -1 in A920, so in IM30 I supose it have to be the same.

I add the log, after adding my custom network, and the remembered networks of the device, where you can check that my custom network is not been added:
the message "Conecta el wifi: ssid:" and "Habilita el wifi:" make reference to addNetwork method

```
Añade la configuración: ID: -1 SSID: "MYCUSTOMNETWORK" PROVIDER-NAME: null BSSID: null FQDN: null PRIO: 0 HIDDEN: false
                                                                                                     NetworkSelectionStatus NETWORK_SELECTION_ENABLED
                                                                                                     hasEverConnected: false
                                                                                                     KeyMgmt: WPA_EAP IEEE8021X Protocols: WPA RSN
                                                                                                     AuthAlgorithms: LEAP
                                                                                                     PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP
                                                                                                     GroupCiphers:
                                                                                                     PSK: *
                                                                                                     sim_num 
                                                                                                    Enterprise config:
                                                                                                    anonymous_identity NULL
                                                                                                    password <removed>
                                                                                                    identity ""carwash""
                                                                                                    proactive_key_caching 1
                                                                                                    IP config:
                                                                                                    IP assignment: UNASSIGNED
                                                                                                    Proxy settings: UNASSIGNED
                                                                                                     cuid=-1 luid=-1 lcuid=0 userApproved=USER_UNSPECIFIED noInternetAccessExpected=false isCarrierNetwork=false roamingFailureBlackListTimeMilli: 1000
                                                                                                    triggeredLow: 0 triggeredBad: 0 triggeredNotHigh: 0
                                                                                                    ticksLow: 0 ticksBad: 0 ticksNotHigh: 0
                                                                                                    triggeredJoin: 0
2023-11-03 15:09:29.577 17790-17831 Tras añadir a la config: [* ID: 0 SSID: "************" PROVIDER-NAME: null BSSID: null FQDN: null PRIO: 22 HIDDEN: false
                                                                                                     NetworkSelectionStatus NETWORK_SELECTION_ENABLED
                                                                                                     hasEverConnected: true
                                                                                                     numAssociation 59
                                                                                                     validatedInternetAccess
                                                                                                     KeyMgmt: WPA_PSK Protocols: WPA RSN
                                                                                                     AuthAlgorithms:
                                                                                                     PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP
                                                                                                     GroupCiphers: TKIP CCMP
                                                                                                     PSK: *
                                                                                                     sim_num *
                                                                                                    Enterprise config:
                                                                                                    altsubject_match NULL
                                                                                                    password <removed>
                                                                                                    ca_path NULL
                                                                                                    subject_match NULL
                                                                                                    engine 0
                                                                                                    client_cert NULL
                                                                                                    anonymous_identity NULL
                                                                                                    ca_cert NULL
                                                                                                    identity NULL
                                                                                                    domain_suffix_match NULL
                                                                                                    key_id NULL
                                                                                                    engine_id NULL
                                                                                                    IP config:
                                                                                                    IP assignment: DHCP
                                                                                                    Proxy settings: NONE
                                                                                                     networkSelectionBSSID=any cuid=1000 cname=android.uid.system:1000 luid=1000 lname=android.uid.system:1000 lcuid=-1 userApproved=USER_APPROVED noInternetAccessExpected=false isCarrierNetwork=false roamingFailureBlackListTimeMilli: 1000
                                                                                                    triggeredLow: 0 triggeredBad: 0 triggeredNotHigh: 0
                                                                                                    ticksLow: 0 ticksBad: 0 ticksNotHigh: 0
                                                                                                    triggeredJoin: 0
                                                                                                    , - DSBLE ID: 1 SSID: "**************" PROVIDER-NAME: null BSSID: null FQDN: null PRIO: 0 HIDDEN: true
                                                                                                     NetworkSelectionStatus NETWORK_SELECTION_ENABLED
                                                                                                     hasEverConnected: false
                                                                                                     KeyMgmt: WPA_PSK Protocols: WPA RSN
                                                                                                     AuthAlgorithms: OPEN
                                                                                                     PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP
                                                                                                     GroupCiphers: TKIP CCMP
                                                                                                     PSK: *
                                                                                                     sim_num *
                                                                                                    Enterprise config:
                                                                                                    altsubject_match NULL
                                                                                                    password <removed>
                                                                                                    ca_path NULL
                                                                                                    subject_match NULL
                                                                                                    engine 0
                                                                                                    client_cert NULL
                                                                                                    anonymous_identity NULL
                                                                                                    ca_cert NULL
                                                                                                    identity NULL
                                                                                                    domain_suffix_match NULL
                                                                                                    key_id NULL
                                                                                                    engine_id NULL
                                                                                                    IP config:
                                                                                                    IP assignment: DHCP
                                                                                                    Proxy settings: NONE
                                                                                                     cuid=10038 cname=com.diusframi.pax luid=10038 lname=com.diusframi.pax lcuid=10038 userApproved=USER_UNSPECIFIED noInternetAccessExpected=false isCarrierNetwork=false roamingFailureBlackListTimeMilli: 1000
                                                                                                    triggeredLow: 0 triggeredBad: 0 triggeredNotHigh: 0
                                                                                                    ticksLow: 0 ticksBad: 0 ticksNotHigh: 0
                                                                                                    triggeredJoin: 0
                                                                                                    ]
2023-11-03 15:09:29.582 17790-17831 Habilita el status de: ssid:"****************" status: 2
2023-11-03 15:09:29.582 17790-17831 Habilita el status de: ssid:"**************" status: 2
2023-11-03 15:09:29.588 17790-17831 Habilita el wifi: -1
2023-11-03 15:09:29.697 17790-17831 Conecta el wifi: ssid:-1
```

So I know that is due to a configuration error in the wifi interface, that make incompatible with Android 7 device.

Here my current configuration:

```
 wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.phase2Method = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.caCertificate = null
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = null
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.identity = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_USER +"\""
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.password = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS +"\""
        wifiConfiguration.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.LEAP)
        wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig = wifiEnterpriseConfig
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_SSID +"\""
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey ="\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS+"\""

        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)

        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)
```

Any clue?

I add all the permission I already have in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 6.0 (API level 23), certain permissions related to Wi-Fi handling require the CHANGE_WIFI_STATE permission, which allows an app to change the Wi-Fi connectivity state.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Also, ensure that your app has the necessary runtime permissions, especially ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION as it's a critical permission for interacting with Wi-Fi settings.

Comment: I've already had these permission added